# Is this syntax or semantic error in c#

Tags: c#, syntax, semantics

I am doing my compiler construction assignment, and designing cfgs for syntax, i just want to know that is this syntax error or semantic error. (Nested Function)

```
void function1()
{
    int a = 0;
    void function2()
    {
        int ae=0;
    }
}
```

should I handle this in syntax or semantic

Comment: Didn't your teachers sad that how to distinguish that?
This is syntax error because there are no nested functions in C# (but anonymous methods are used as nested methods)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a syntax error because your cannot define a named function within a function.  However you can use [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/bb397687.aspx) to create unnamed functions that use the scope of the current function.

Comment: Also tell me whether it is syntax or semantic?
void function ()
{
break;
}
means, break in function

Comment: @SyedTalhaHai: Also syntax. break is not allowed directly in a method (must be in cycle or switch). Are you planning to ask each part of you homework here? :-)